# Como puedo hacer que dos clases en diferentes paquetes hereden

Tags: java, clase, packages

tengo la siguiente distribucion en mi proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es si yo puedo hacer que la clase "App_Circulo" herede de las clases que hay en el package Geometria.
Un saludo.

Comment: Lo has intentado?

Comment: Lo he intentado con un import + nom_paquete, pero al estar la app en un paquete y la clase circulo en otro no me deja.
Tambien con un extends, pero nada

Comment: Lo que planteas es el escenario más común que podemos encontrarnos en nuestras aplicaciones. Si puedes comparte lo que has intentado y los errores que tienes.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas ya que no das elementos del error asumo que sea por el nivel de acceso de la clase. Primero debes fijarte en el modificador de acceso de la clase en cuestión, debido a que si no tiene ninguno especificado se asume que es Default, o sea, solo tiene visibilidad a nivel de paquete. Por lo que o mueves la clase al paquete requerido, o cambias el nivel de acceso de la clase a uno que te permita la visibilidad fuera del paquete.
Ejemplo si tienes:

```
class Circulo {
 ...
}
```

sólo tendrá acceso a nivel de paquete por lo que fuera del paquete no tendrá visibilidad. Otro ejemplo sería:

```
public final class Circulo {
...
}
```

Acá el `final` evitaría que otras clases hereden de la clase.